# Typo3 scheduler: Can i somehow execute Action of controllers of my extension with it? Or how to run my own code with it?

Tags: php, typo3, scheduler

A while ago i was tasked to program a Typo3 extension to write so called .conf files for the icinga2 montoring tool (has nothing to do with Typo3). Still let me explain some parts of it: Basically the backend user needs to create records of records of specific classes and set values for each records properties. Then i need to process the records to create these .conf files with the specific values with a php script.

I was tasked to use the scheduler in Typo3 for this. And here come the problems: How do i use this? I checked the documentation (https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/scheduler/Introduction/Index.html), but i still can't wrap my head around how to use it for my task. I can easily write an Action in a controller of a class to be executed in the frontend and in turn generate the con files... basically manually without the scheduler. But where do i put my php code to be run by the scheduler? I somehow seem not to understand the basical principle of the scheduler. Can i just run an Action of a specific controller of a class of my extension like i would in the Frontend via the scheduler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you use a command controller for this task.

The [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseFluidBook/10-Outlook/3-Command-controllers.html) shows how to create a command controller, which also may accept arguments.

Command controller tasks can directly be executed by TYPO3 scheduler (see screenshot below)

[image]

You may even configure task arguments for command controller tasks in TYPO3 scheduler.

Comment: OK, my problem right now is: Where should i put the code exactly?
The documentation tells me: "A CommandController needs to be located at Classes/Command/. "

Does this mean the file has to be created in the Classes/Command/ directory of my extension?

Comment: Yes, it need to be located in that directory, but shouldn't be a problem, should it?

Comment: It seems i'm doing something totally wrong. I tried this step by step instruction: http://blog.scwebs.in/typo3/typo3-commandcontroller-in-scheduler-task

But it doesn't show up in the Scheduler.

Comment: It should show up in scheduler task at the end of the form, if you select "Extbase CommandController Task" in the Class dropdown.

Comment: OK, what i did was creating the Command directory in the Classes directory of my extension. Then i created a CommandController.php file in it (it uses the namespace of my extension - vendor\extension\command) and put some code in it. In the ext_localconf i added the $GLOBALS line. I think there is my error located. I'm not sure were exactly i should put the $GLOBALS line there... (the line looks like this: $GLOBALS[‘TYPO3_CONF_VARS’][‘SC_OPTIONS’][‘extbase’][‘commandControllers’][] = 'Cjk\Icingaconfgen\Command\SimpleCommandController';). Should i put it directly under the opening php tag?

Comment: The Command Controller should be registered in ext_localconf.php like shown here: https://github.com/derhansen/sf_event_mgt/blob/master/ext_localconf.php#L56

The corresponding PHP for the command should be like shown here: https://github.com/derhansen/sf_event_mgt/blob/master/Classes/Command/CleanupCommandController.php

Make sure, you name you postfix your command with "Command" - e.g. generateconfigCommand

Comment: I did everything you said, but after countless attempts it still doesn't work. The only Command that is in the drop down is "Lang language: update"...

I guess ihave to give up for now.

Comment: Sometimes i could slap myself: It works now! I only had to deactivate and the activate the extension again to make the changes work.